# Mapbox Studio: How to upload glyphs or sprite for custom markers

Tags: mapbox-studio

I am wondering how I can view the available or upload new glyphs or sprites into Mapbox Studio. I want to style some markers with custom icons and can't figure out where the default glyphs are coming from and how i can change that in Mapbox Studio.

Answer (score 2):

This is the official documents from Mapbox:

https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers/#locate-custom-styles-images

Log in to your account, locate your custom style, and follow the instructions attached in the link above.

When you create your custom styles, you can upload your own .svg files with the icons you wish to use (some restrictions apply).

**Some Extra Details About Use**

Seeing that Mapbox is moving towards use of Mapbox GL, in your geojson, you reference the name of the marker that is declared in your geojson source, so it could look like so:

Geojson:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.26, 51.52]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Some Title",
        "marker-symbol": "my-custom-marker"
    }
}
```

When you add your layer, reference the marker like so

```
"layout": {
    "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}"
}
```